# Checking Errors when signing up

Tags: php, html

I have added a dynamic selector in my html to select gender and country when signing up,now the question is how do i use the IF and Else short Hand to check if the user has selected both so that the sign up is complete,

this is my selector i added

```
<div>Gender:</div>
    <select id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="m">Male</option>
      <option value="f">Female</option>
    </select>
    <div>Country:</div>
    <select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <?php include_once("country_list.php"); ?>
    </select>
    <div>
```

Comment: First of all, you will require a `name` attribute in order for PHP to process it. `id` will serve no purpose unless using javascript/jquery to validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a `name` attribute to your form inputs.

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
<select id="country" name="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
```

You can then check if it has been set.

```
if(!isset($_POST['gender'])) 
{
  //Do what you need to if it is not set (such as a redirect)
}
if(!isset($_POST['country'])) 
{
  //Do what you need to if it is not set (such as a redirect)
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok thanks ... i think this one is close and similar to what i had in mind ,let me try

Comment: Great. Let me know if you need any more help.